# How to upload large file through salesforce apex

Tags: file-upload, salesforce, apex

I want to upload file upto 20MB through salesforce apex
How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64440879/313628, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63185542/313628, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57872218/313628

Comment: without api It's possible?

Comment: How "without API". Your question is vague, upload to Salesforce? Or from Salesforce to 3rd party server? You somehow have an org that doesn't have API access (Group Edition etc) but has apex development capabilities? Why do you think you need/don't need apex for it. Form your question better. Have you seen "Files Connect"?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce is limited to handling files up to 10 MB in size. To handle larger files, you'll need to use a different approach.

One possible solution is to use the Salesforce REST API directly to upload the file.

You can use salesforce standard api of sObjects from content version..
like in this way..

```
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

    String base64Data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBody);

    String jsonInput = '{"Title":"' + fileName + '", "PathOnClient":"' + fileName + '", "VersionData":"' + base64Data + '", "FirstPublishLocationId":"<your_record_id_here>"}';

    request.setBody(jsonInput);

    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
```

This might be help.